# PHP function json_decode decodes float value with zeros after point as int

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string that contains some key with the following value: 123.00. When I use json_decode function I get the decoded string where the previous key equal to 123, not to 123.00. Is there a way to correct decode such values without wrapping into quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently being brought up as a PHP bug:

**Bug Report**: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50224

In the future, there may be functionality to pass a flag through the `options` parameter for stricter typing. For now, however, wrapping it in quotes will have to suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the link!

Comment: Fixed as of PHP 7.0, new option available for json_decode, `JSON_PRESERVE_FRACTIONAL_PART`

Comment: I believe it should be `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION`. See  [respective commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/993/commits/95cef47afb0b5329915a178d34cf27efcb54607b)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible!

Answer (score 1):

```
//convert the json to a string before json_decode
$res = preg_replace( '/next_cursor":(\d+)/', 'next_cursor":"\1"', $json );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format($number, 2)
```

output the number through that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option, for example:

```
$json = json_decode($input, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

Careful though, this only works with PHP 5.4+!